# Struggle with mongoose query, pushing different Objects into different arrays in a single deeply nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, patch

I just can't figure out the query and even if it's allowed to write a single query to push 4 different objects into 4 different arrays deeply nested inside the user Object.

I receive PATCH request from front-end which's body looks like this:

```
{
  bodyweight: 80,
  waist: 60,
  biceps: 20,
  benchpress: 50,
  timestamp: 1645996168125
}
```

I want to create 4 Objects and push them into user's data in Mongo Atlas

`{date:1645996168125, value:80}` into `user.stats.bodyweight` <-array

`{date:1645996168125, value:60}` into `user.stats.waist` <-array

...etc

I am trying to figure out second argument for:

```
let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({id:req.params.id}, ???)
```

But i am happy to update it with any other mongoose method if possible.

PS: I am not using `_id` given by mongoDB on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator. It accepts paths as the field names, so you can specify a path to each of the arrays.

I assume the fields included in your request are fixed (the same four property names / arrays for every request)

```js
let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: req.params.id },
  {
    $push: {
      "stats.bodyweight": {
        date: 1645996168125,
        value: 80,
      },
      "stats.waist": {
        date: 1645996168125,
        value: 60,
      },
      // ...
    },
  }
);
```

If the fields are dynamic, use an object and if conditions, like this:

```js
const update = {};
if ("bodyweight" in req.body) {
  update["stats.bodyweight"] = {
    date: 1645996168125,
    value: 80,
  };
}
// ...

let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: req.params.id },
  {
    $push: update,
  }
);
```

The if condition is just to demonstrate the principle, you'll probably want to use stricter type checking / validation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
     {id:req.params.id},
     {$addToSet:
          {"stats.bodyweight":{date:1645996168125, value:80} } 
     }
                           )
```

Comment: 1.This looks like updating one of 4
2.I tried anyway but i get error: ```MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField```